# R - Find matching rows from different dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with records that are either debit or credit. The credit records have an exact match at the debit. I need to remove the credit and the linked debit record from my dataframe.

The problem is that the records are not unique, so i dont want to remove all the records that matches, just one. (so no anti-join possible). The values in the rows are an exact match and they have the same columns.

My approach was to split the dataframe up in "debit"-dataframe **(ddc)** and a "credit"-dataframe **(dcc)**. Now loop through each row of the credit-dataframe and find the matching row in the debit-dataframe and remove this. Note that they have to match by several columns.

When i try to use the match-function it keeps calculating and i feel it doesn't work. 
What i try now is:

```
ddc <- ddc[!(ddc[match(dcc[1,],ddc),]),]
```

What i aim for is:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dcc)){
ddc <- ddc[!(ddc[match(dcc[i,],ddc),]),]
}
```

The result should be a debit-dataframe where one match of each row of the credit-dataframe is removed.
So that if ddc has 10 rows and dcc 2 rows, the new ddc will have 8 rows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Example data:

```
dcc               ddc                    new ddc

x1 x2 x3 x4 x5     x1  x2  x3  x4  x5     x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
1  2  3  5  6      1   2   2   3   5      1    2   2   3   5
1  3  2  3  5      1   2   3   3   3      1    2   3   3   3 
1  2  3  5  6      1   2   2   3   5      1    2   2   3   5
1  5  6  7  3      1   5   5   2   3      1    5   5   2   3 
                   1   3   2   3   5      1    3   2   3   5
                   1   2   3   5   6
                   1   3   2   3   5
                   1   5   6   7   3
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: I can't provide the data but i can make an example of the data.

Comment: that would be helpful, yes please do, and add with it the expected output.

Comment: `unique(d[, setdiff(names(d), "credit_debit_column")])`

Comment: I tried unique but the records are not unique. They can have multiple matches but i only want to remove 1 on the debit for each on the credit. Could you explain what your code somewhat does? Maybe i can use parts of it.

Comment: With your example, does `dplyr::anti_join(ddc, dcc)` work? Not sure what I'm missing unless your eg doesn't cover all the use cases

Comment: ah never mind, its the final row (1, 3, 2, 3, 5) that's causing the issue as you want to just remove the first occurence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `anti_join` like [Jonny Phelps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5990938/jonny-phelps) mentioned in the comments above, however I would first add some sort of ranking column to make sure that I keep the duplicates, here's what I'm suggesting:

```
# read the data
dcc <- read.table(text = 'x1 x2 x3 x4 x5    
1  2  3  5  6      
1  3  2  3  5      
1  2  3  5  6      
1  5  6  7  3 ', header = TRUE)

ddc <- read.table(text = 'x1  x2  x3  x4  x5     
1   2   2   3   5     
1   2   3   3   3      
1   2   2   3   5      
1   5   5   2   3      
1   3   2   3   5      
1   2   3   5   6
1   3   2   3   5
1   5   6   7   3', header = TRUE)

# Add the ranking column in ddc
ddc <- ddc %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  mutate(rank_row = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
# Add a dummy ranking column in dcc, which is always = 1
dcc <- dcc %>% mutate(rank_row = 1)

# and now the anti_join by = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "rank_row") or by = names(ddc)
anti_join(ddc, dcc, by = names(ddc))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I already tried to use the anti_join but by using the ranking column i can detect duplicates and make those unique. This way the anti_join works. I did the rankings in the dcc aswell because there were duplictes too. Now i am left with 500 records too many but i am i ok with that.